# Regex to find text immediately following 1st occurrence of a word

Tags: regex

Say I'm looking at a stream of a web page, and near the top it says `About 367 results` etc etc. I would like to get the number (of results) following the word `About` with a regex. Does anyone have an example? Or a bone-head tutorial for that matter? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to capture the first group in for the regex `/\bAbout\s+(\d+)/`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the number as follows

```
About (\d+)
```

or

```
About (\d+) results
```

In both cases the digits will be captured.